# Snakemake with a script generating many intermediate files

Tags: snakemake

I want to know what is the best practice to write a rule(s) for a script with many intermediate files?

A R script sample is like this:

```
data <- read_rds(snakemake@input[["data"]])

# generate and save many plots for sanity check
plt1
ggsave("plt1.pdf", plt1) 

plt2
ggsave("plt2.pdf", plt2)

# and many other figs

# No actual output
```

The rule I wrote:

```py
rule transform:
  input:
    data : "data.rds"
  output:
    touch("script.Rout")
  script: "script.R"
```

Notice that there is **no** actual output from `script.R`. This file is mainy used as some sanity check (manually done after running this rule) by plotting some draft figures. The figures will not be used as any inputs for future workflows.

In this case, is my solution proper? Are there better approaches?

Thank you!

Comment: When you say intermediary files, do you mean the PDFs by that? What's your reason for not declaring them as outputs? That you think you would have to write them out manually or because you don't consider them 'output'?  Also I'm confused by your statement that you use the empty output file as a sanity check **by** plotting figures. The file is empty, so doesn't plot anything. Do you mean you run snakemake asking for this output file to make this plotting rule execute? In that case, you can just ask for the rule to be run explicitly: `snakemake -c1 transform`

Comment: Hi Cornelius, because usually I plot a lot of figures and export them as pdfs and manually look over the pdfs to see whether they make sense. Since these plots are only used for this checking purpose and will never be used in any subsequent rules, it seems to be an overkill to declare them as outputs? I think explicitly running `transform` makes sense and that's what I am doing now, just that I do not declare the pdfs as outputs (too many of them and names cannot be easily predefined as wildcards)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Snakemake rule doesn't actually need to declare any output, so you could simply leave out the output bit.

In general, it's good to be explicit about the output of your rules for the following reasons:

- Snakemake checks whether the output is actually produced and provides an informative error message when the output is not produced after the rule finished.
- Snakemake can delete all output that is produced (`--delete-all-output`) but only if the output has been declared.

Another reason to declare and create output (like through `touch` as you do) is so that the rule can automatically be called by another rule. Say you have a "rule all" that triggers your actual data analysis, but you want it to create plots, too. You could then declare `script.Rout` as an input of this rule, and the script would automatically be called.

Since `script.Rout` is an empty file, declared potentially just so that another file can automatically execute this rule, you could add a `temp` to it, so that it gets removed in the end and you don't have to clean it up yourself:

```yaml
output: temp(touch("script.Rout"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't use the files for anything else, it should be ok.

There is an argument for explicitly listing the outputs though.  That would provide support for removing all output files through snakemake and would detect cases where your script failed silently halfway through.  If the outputs are really `figure{i}.pdf`, it's as easy as adding an `expand('figure{i}.pdf', i=range(MAX)`.